rabbitmq podman clustering Failed
I'm currently attempting to cluster RabbitMQ into three nodes on a cloud service.
To do this, I've opened the following ports on ACG: 35672, 15672, 5671, 5672, 25672, and 4369.
Additionally, I've ensured that the Erlang cookie values are identical.
I've also added the IP addresses of both myself and the servers to be clustered into /etc/hosts.
[root@sub002 ~]# podman exec rabbit rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@sub001
Clustering node rabbit@sub002 with rabbit@sub001 ...
Error: unable to connect to nodes [rabbit@sub001]: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@sub001]

rabbit@sub001:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on sub001
  * node rabbit@sub001 up, 'rabbit' application running

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-08@sub002'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: 3+AAnpHjM54MbLcsYWIsyw==

When I created servers in Proxmox using the same image and method, and then ran them with Docker, they were created without any issues.
I'm not sure what else I should do.
